# Can I get KnownNat n to imply KnownNat (n * 3), etc?

Tags: haskell, singleton-type

I'm working with data types of this shape, using `V` from `linear`:

```
type Foo n = V (n * 3) Double -> Double
```

Having it fixed on `n` is pretty important, because I want to be able to ensure that I'm passing in the right number of elements at compile-time.  This is a part of my program that already works well, independent of what I'm doing here.

For any `KnownNat n`, I can generate a `Foo n` satisfying the behavior that my program needs.  For the purposes of this question it can be something silly like

```
mkFoo :: KnownNat (n * 3) => Foo n
mkFoo = sum
```

Or for a more meaningful example, it can generate a random `V` of the same length and use `dot` on the two.  The `KnownNat` constraint here is redundant, but in reality, it's needed to do make a `Foo`.  I make one `Foo` and use it for my entire program (or with multiple inputs), so this guarantees me that whenever I use it, I'm using on things with the same length, and on things that the structure of the `Foo` dictates.

And finally, I have a function that makes inputs for a `Foo`:

```
bar :: KnownNat (n * 3) => Proxy n -> [V (n * 3) Double]
```

*bar* is actually the reason why i'm using `n * 3` as a type function, instead of just manually expanding it out.  The reason is that `bar` might do its job by using three vectors of length `n` and appending them all together as a vector of length `n * 3`.  Also, `n` is a much more meaningful parameter to the function, semantically, than `n * 3`.  This also lets me disallow improper values like `n`'s that aren't multiples of 3, etc.

Now, before, everything worked fine as long as I defined a type synonym at the beginning:

```
type N = 5
```

And I can just then pass in `Proxy :: Proxy N` to `bar`, and use `mkFoo :: Foo N`.  And everything worked fine.

```
-- works fine
doStuff :: [Double]
doStuff = let inps = bar (Proxy :: Proxy N)
          in  map (mkFoo :: Foo N) inps
```

But now I want to be able to adjust `N` during runtime by loading information from a file, or from command line arguments.

I tried doing it by calling `reflectNat`:

```
doStuff :: Integer -> Double
doStuff n = reflectNat 5 $ \pn@(Proxy :: Proxy n) ->
              let inps = bar (Proxy :: Proxy n)
              in  map (mkFoo :: Foo n) inps
```

But...`bar` and `mkFoo` require `KnownNat (n * 3)`, but `reflectNat` just gives me `KnownNat n`.

Is there any way I can generalize the proof that `reflectNat` gives me to satisfy `foo` ?

Comment: No, you can't. If you can give some more context about what you're trying to accomplish, someone may be able to help.

Comment: Try writing a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (sscce.org), so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: @dfeuer added concrete examples with what I think are adequate explanations of motivations for design decisions.  thanks!

Comment: Do you do heavy computation with `Nat`? If not, then singleton Peano naturals would be a much better choice.

Comment: Two critical things are missing with `GHC.TypeLits`: induction and the singleton versions of the builtin `Nat` type families. The latter could be implemented with unsafe tricks, but the former seems hopeless to me.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, if you're willing to do unsafe tricks you might be able to fake induction with an explicit eliminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I post another answer as it is more direct, editing the previous won't make sense.

In fact using the trick (popularised if not invented by Edward Kmett), from [reflections](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1/docs/Data-Reflection.html) `reifyNat`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy
import Unsafe.Coerce

newtype MagicNat3 r = MagicNat3 (forall (n :: Nat). KnownNat (n * 3) => Proxy n -> r)

trickValue :: Integer -> Integer
trickValue = (*3)

-- No type-level garantee that the function will be called with (n * 3)
-- you have to believe us
trick :: forall a n. KnownNat n => Proxy n -> (forall m. KnownNat (m * 3) => Proxy m -> a) -> a
trick p f = unsafeCoerce (MagicNat3 f :: MagicNat3 a) (trickValue (natVal p)) Proxy

test :: forall m. KnownNat (m * 3) => Proxy m -> Integer
test _ = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy (m * 3))
```

So when you run it:

```
λ *Main > :t trick (Proxy :: Proxy 4) test :: Integer
trick (Proxy :: Proxy 4) test :: Integer :: Integer
λ *Main > trick (Proxy :: Proxy 4) test :: Integer
12
```

The trick is based on the fact that in GHC the one member class dictionaries (like `KnownNat`) are represented by the member itself. In `KnownNat` situation it turns out to be `Integer`. So we just `unsafeCoerce` it there. Universal quantification makes it sound from the outside.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  It's "sound", but it looks like this can only work if `trickValue`, the function, is the same as whatever type family you're applying to `m` in the type signature of `trick` (in this case, `(*3)`).  As far as I can see, the compiler won't help me if i have `trickValue = (*4)` instead.  Is there any formulation where I can't do something silly like this?

Comment: @JustinL. I'm afraid you'll need a fully dependent language there. Either you'd have inefficient `Nat` representation with singletons, or you have to use `unsafeCoerce` and verify the correctness by other means than type system.

Comment: So sad.  Well, I think I can get `V` from *linear* to work with arbitrary peano nats that I can cook up or use from singletons, but I lose the nice type lits syntax.  If only there was a way to have type lits also be polymorphic like term numerical lits.  thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 6):

So, three months later, I have been going back and forth on good ways to accomplish this, but I finally settled on an actual very succinct trick that doesn't require any throwaway newtypes; it involves using a `Dict` from the *[constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints)* library;  you could easily write a:

```
natDict :: KnownNat n => Proxy n -> Dict (KnownNat n)
natDict _ = Dict

triple :: KnownNat n => Proxy n -> Dict (KnownNat (n * 3))
triple p = reifyNat (natVal p * 3) $
             \p3 -> unsafeCoerce (natDict p3)
```

And once you get `Dict (KnownNat (n * 3)`, you can pattern match on it to get the `(n * 3)` instance in scope:

```
case triple (Proxy :: Proxy n) of
  Dict -> -- KnownNat (n * 3) is in scope
```

You can actually set these up as generic, too:

```
addNats :: (KnownNat n, KnownNat m) => Proxy n -> Proxy m -> Dict (KnownNat (n * m))
addNats px py = reifyNat (natVal px + natVal py) $
                  \pz -> unsafeCoerce (natDict pz)
```

Or, you can make them operators and you can use them to "combine" Dicts:

```
infixl 6 %+
infixl 7 %*
(%+) :: Dict (KnownNat n) -> Dict (KnownNat m) -> Dict (KnownNat (n + m))
(%*) :: Dict (KnownNat n) -> Dict (KnownNat m) -> Dict (KnownNat (n * m))
```

And you can do things like:

```
case d1 %* d2 %+ d3 of
  Dict -> -- in here, KnownNat (n1 * n2 + n3) is in scope
```

I've wrapped this up in a nice library, **[typelits-witnesses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-witnesses)** that I've been using.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very descriptive, so I'll try my best to feel blanks:

Let's assume that `Blah n` is `Proxy n`.

I also assume that `reflectNat` is a way to call universally quantified (over typelevel `Nat`) function, using term-level natural number.

I don't know better way than writing your own `reflectNat` providing that

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

data Vec a (n :: Nat) where
  Nil  :: Vec a 0
  Cons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (1 + n)

vecToList :: Vec a n -> [a]
vecToList Nil = []
vecToList (Cons h t) = h : vecToList t

repl :: forall n a. KnownNat n => Proxy n -> a -> Vec a n
repl p x = undefined -- this is a bit tricky with Nat from GHC.TypeLits, but possible

foo :: forall (n :: Nat). KnownNat (1 + n) => Proxy n -> Vec Bool (1 + n)
foo _ = repl (Proxy :: Proxy (1 + n)) True

-- Here we have to write our own version of 'reflectNat' providing right 'KnownNat' instances
-- so we can call `foo`
reflectNat :: Integer -> (forall n. KnownNat (1 + n) => Proxy (n :: Nat) -> a) -> a
reflectNat = undefined

test :: [Bool]
test = reflectNat 5 $ \p -> vecToList (foo p)
```

---

Alternatively, using `singletons` you can use `SomeSing`. Then types will be different

```
reflectNat :: Integer -> (forall (n :: Nat). SomeSing (n :: Nat) -> a) -> a
```

I.e. instead of magic dict `KnownNat` you have concrete singleton value. Thus in `foo` you'd need to construct `SomeSing (1 + n)` explicitly, given `SomeSing n` -- which is quite simple.

In run-time both `KnownNat` dictionary and `SomeSing` value will be passed around carring the number value, and explicit is IMHO better in this situation.p)

Comment: It looks like `reflectNat`'s definition in `reflections` is basically similar (it uses `unsafeCoerce`), so this might be an okay road to go down :)  I'll look into `singletons`...do you know how I'd write `reflectNat` in `singletons` fashion?  `Sing Nat` seems to provide something that I can't pattern match on/a single constructor like `Proxy`, so I'm not sure how to wrangle with it.

Comment: Can't say about `singleton-2.0` as there aren't haddocks online, but for `singletons-1.1.2.1` seems that it uses `SNat :: KnownNat n => Sing Nat n` - so actually no difference. I was in my simple *PeanoNat* world :(