# How to satisfy constraints on existentially quantified values?

Tags: haskell

In an attempt at learning how to work with dependent data types in haskell I encountered the following problem:

Suppose you have a function such as:

```
mean :: ((1 GHC.TypeLits.<=? n) ~ 'True, GHC.TypeLits.KnownNat n) => R n -> ℝ
```

defined in the `hmatrix` library, then how do you use this on a vector that has an existential type? E.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators       #-}

import Data.Proxy                   (Proxy (..))
import GHC.TypeLits
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static

getUserInput =
  let userInput = 3   -- pretend it's unknown at compile time
      seed      = 42
  in existentialCrisis seed userInput

existentialCrisis seed userInput
  | userInput <= 0 = 0
  | otherwise =
    case someNatVal userInput of
      Nothing -> undefined -- let's ignore this case for now
      Just (SomeNat (proxy :: Proxy n)) ->
        let someVector = randomVector seed Gaussian :: R n
        in mean someVector -- I know that 'n > 0' but the compiler doesn't
```

This gives the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘1 <=? n’ with ‘'True’
    arising from a use of ‘mean’
```

Makes sense indeed, but after some googling and fiddling around, I could not find out how to deal with this. How can I get hold of an `n :: Nat`, based on user input, such that it satisfies the `1 <= n` constraint?. I believe it must be possible since the `someNatVal` function already succeeds in satisfying the `KnownNat` constraint based on the condition that the input is not negative.

It seems to me that this is a common thing when working with dependent types, and maybe the answer is obvious but I don't see it.

So my question:

*How, in general, can I bring an existential type in scope satisfying the constraints required for some function?*

My attempts:

- To my surprise, even the following modification

  ```
      let someVector = randomVector seed Gaussian :: R (n + 1)
  ```

  gave a type error:

  ```
  • Couldn't match type ‘1 <=? (n + 1)’ with ‘'True’
      arising from a use of ‘mean’
  ```

  Also, adding an extra instance to `<=?` to prove this equality does not work as `<=?` is closed.
- I tried an approach combining `GADTs` with typeclasses as in [this answer to a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495696/2496293) but could not make it work.

Comment: You need a function like `forall n . Proxy n -> ((1 <=? n) ~ 'True => x) -> ((1 <=? n) ~ 'False => x) -> x` which replaces the value-level pattern match (i.e. `.. | userInput <= 0 = 0`).

Comment: To implement such a function, I still need to be able to inspect `n` in such a way that the compiler knows whether `1 <=? n` eqauls `'True` or `'False`. So this just seems to move the problem to another place.

Comment: @SamDeMeyer The "typelits-witnesses" provides some extra functions for `GHC.TypeLits` that help with these kinds of tasks. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387963/1364288 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39812205/1364288

Comment: @danidiaz Thx, I had already started writing similar code as in `typelits-witnesses` before I read your answer. It's nice to see that someone else already implemented it for me :).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492754/could-not-deduce-knownnat-in-two-existentials-with-respect-to-the-singletons-lib/41496362#41496362

Comment: @gallais, thx, `user3237465`'s answer in that post is also quite useful since it has no extra dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @danidiaz for pointing me in the right direction, the `typelist-witnesses` documentation provides a [nearly direct answer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-witnesses-0.2.3.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits-Compare.html) to my question. Seems like I was using the wrong search terms when googling for a solution.

So here is a self contained compileable solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}

import Data.Proxy                   (Proxy (..))
import Data.Type.Equality           ((:~:)(Refl))
import GHC.TypeLits
import GHC.TypeLits.Compare
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static

existentialCrisis :: Int -> Int -> IO (Double)
existentialCrisis seed userInput =
    case someNatVal (fromIntegral userInput) of
      Nothing -> print "someNatVal failed" >> return 0
      Just (SomeNat (proxy :: Proxy n)) ->
        case isLE (Proxy :: Proxy 1) proxy of
          Nothing -> print "isLE failed" >> return 0
          Just Refl ->
            let someVector = randomVector seed Gaussian :: R n
            in do
              print userInput
              -- I know that 'n > 0' and so does the compiler
              return (mean someVector)
```

And it works with input only known at runtime:

```
λ: :l ExistentialCrisis.hs 
λ: existentialCrisis 41 1
(0.2596687587224799 :: R 1)
0.2596687587224799
*Main
λ: existentialCrisis 41 0
"isLE failed"
0.0
*Main
λ: existentialCrisis 41 (-1)
"someNatVal failed"
0.0
```

It seems like `typelist-witnesses` does a lot `unsafeCoerce`ing under the hood. But the interface is type-safe so it doesn't really matter that much for practical use cases.

**EDIT:**

If this question was of interest to you, might also find this post interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41615278/2496293