# How can I tell GHC to satisfy a type-level <= constraint if I know it's true at runtime?

Tags: haskell

I have a type parametrized by a natural number `n`:

```
data MyType (n :: Nat) = MyType
```

Operations on this type only make sense when `n > 0`, so I specified that as a constraint:

```
myFunction :: (KnownNat n, 1 <= n) => MyType n -> MyType n
myFunction = id
```

(Note that real versions of these functions *do* use `n` by turning it into a value with `natVal`.)

I want to create an existential type (`SomeMyType`) that lets us choose an `n` at runtime:

```
data SomeMyType where
  SomeMyType :: forall n. (KnownNat n, 1 <= n) => MyType n -> SomeMyType
```

To produce values of `SomeMyType`, I'm writing a `someMyTypeVal` function that works like `someNatVal`:

```
someMyTypeVal :: Integer -> Maybe SomeMyType
someMyTypeVal n
  | n > 0 = case someNatVal n of
      Just (SomeNat (_ :: p n)) -> Just (SomeMyType (MyType @n))
      Nothing                   -> Nothing
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

This would work perfectly fine without the `1 <= n` constraint, but with the constraint I get the following type error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘1 <=? n’ with ‘'True’
    arising from a use of ‘SomeMyType’
```

How can I get around this limitation? Since I've checked that `n > 0` at runtime, I would not mind using an operation like `unsafeCoerce` here to convince GHC that `1 <= n` is true—but I can't *just* use `unsafeCoerce` because that would lose the type-level value of `n`.

What's the best way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After poking around a bit more, I found [Justin L's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387963/286871). He wrapped up his solution into the [`typelits-witnesses`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-witnesses) package which I was able to use to solve this problem pretty cleanly:

```
someMyTypeVal :: Integer -> Maybe SomeMyType
someMyTypeVal n = someNatVal n >>= check
  where check :: SomeNat -> Maybe SomeMyType
        check (SomeNat (_ :: p n)) = case (SNat @1) %<=? (SNat @n) of
          LE Refl -> Just (SomeMyType (MyType @n))
          NLE _ _ -> Nothing
```

`a %<=? b` lets us compare two type-level natural numbers and gives us a witness for whether `a` is less than `b` (`LE`) or not (`NLE`). This gives us the extra constraint in the `LE` case to return a `SomeMyType`, but trying to do that in the `NLE` case would still give us the "can't match ‘1 <=? n’ with ‘'True’" error.

Note the explicit type signature for `check`—without it, the type of `check` is inferred as `check :: SomeNat -> Maybe a` and I would get the following type error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘SomeMyType’
   ‘a’ is untouchable
     inside the constraints: 'True ~ (1 <=? n)
```

With the explicit type signature everything works and the code is even (reasonably) readable.

Answer (score 1):

As a more direct answer, the constraint `1 <= n` is just a type alias for `1 <=? n ~ 'True`.  You can unsafely create such a type equality constraint with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Type.Equality
import GHC.TypeLits
import Unsafe.Coerce

unsafeDeclarePositive :: p n -> (1 <=? n) :~: 'True
unsafeDeclarePositive _ = unsafeCoerce Refl
```

which is more or less what `typelits-witnesses` is doing under the hood.

With that definition in place, the following should type-check:

```
someMyTypeVal :: Integer -> Maybe SomeMyType
someMyTypeVal n
  | n > 0 = case someNatVal n of
      Just (SomeNat (pxy :: p n)) ->
        case unsafeDeclarePositive pxy of
          Refl -> Just (SomeMyType (MyType @n))
      Nothing -> Nothing
  | otherwise = Nothing
```